# Why does changing a truecrypt password take such a long time?

Tags: linux, truecrypt

I am changing the password of a truecrypt file container. This takes around 1 minute. Why?

```
time truecrypt --text --change /tmp/user1.tc --keyfiles= --new-keyfiles= --password=known --new-password=known --random-source=/dev/null"
```

If I use strace I see that it basically does not do anything: it simply reads lots of random data from /dev/urandom (even if i specified /dev/null as random source) and finally changes the password:

```
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 6
read(6, "\36&{\351\212\212\343\202\34\313\242\312I\326\235\245\224\300\354O)\270Q\200 \201J\227\224\311_\212\367"..., 640) = 640
close(6)                                = 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Truecrypt is generating a new key to be associated with the new passphrase.  In order to achice the random nature to generate a secure key, truecrypt samples many different sources over a little while(1min).  It's necessary for a new secure key.  Using /dev/null is not recomended!  Hope this clears it up.

Comment: In fact, using `/dev/null` as a source for anything _will not work_, because the null device is only a "sink"; you can't read anything from it. The opposite would be `/dev/zero`, which is read-only and outputs null bytes... but really, using _that_ as a "random number" source is asking to be shot.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used this to create a random source:

```
         dd if=/dev/urandom of=/root/rn bs=1b count=320
```

I chose 320 because truecrypt prompts for 320 random chars if you don't specify an random source.

`/dev/urandom` is somewhat better than `/dev/zero`

```
truecrypt --text --change --keyfiles= --new-keyfiles= --password=pw --new-password=newpw --random-source=/root/rn /dev/xvgf1
```

Comment: This sounds like its asking for trouble using this.  I suggest one sticks with the default implementation.